# Simplifying the regex "ab|a|b"

Tags: regex, redundancy, simplify

(How) could the following regex be simplified:

```
ab|a|b
```

?

I'm looking for a less redundant one, i.e. with only one `a` and one `b`. Is it possible?

Some tries:

```
a?b?       # matches empty string while shouldn't
ab?|b      # still two b
```

---

Note that the real regex has more complicated `a` and `b` parts, i.e. not a single char but inner subregexes let's say.

Comment: my intuition tells me that it can't be simplified

Comment: Is there a reason you need to simplify this regex?  While there is a bit of redundancy, it is still very simple and easy to read.

Comment: @leppie: that matches aa and bb, which are both invalid

Comment: @Jeff: Good point, I guess it cant be simplified.

Comment: @Jeff The example is quite readable as you said, but the *real* regex has more complicated `a` and `b` parts.

Comment: @sp00m: Consider breaking it into three regular expressions, then.  If you simply split it on the '|' characters, you are left with three simpler regular expressions, each of which is more maintainable than the original, and they can be tested against separately.

Comment: How about: `(ab?)|(a?b)` ? Does not seem simpler and the DFA analysis would probably build the same parse tree.

Comment: @sp00m this (as so many other regex questions) depends somewhat on your regex flavor. so which language or environment are you using this in?

Comment: @m.buettner Let's say Java's one, but this is more a *general regex question*, i.e. let's considier a flavor that supports every regex clauses (not like JavaScript's for example).

Comment: @sp00m then you can't do any better than this, except for Jeff's solution or string concatenation

Comment: With lookarounds : (?=.)a?b? or a?b?(?<=.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Perl or some PCRE engine (like PHP's `preg_` functions), you can refer to previous groups in the pattern, like this:

```
/(a)(b)|(?1)|(?2)/
```

The main purpose of this feature is to support recursion, but it can be used for pattern reuse as well.

Note that in this case you cannot get around capturing `a` and `b` in the first alternation, which incurs some (possibly) unnecessary overhead. To avoid this, you can define the groups inside a conditional that is never executed. The canonical way to do this is to use `(?(DEFINE)...)` group (which checks if a named `DEFINE` group matched anything, but of course that group doesn't exist):

```
/(?(DEFINE)(a)(b))(?1)(?2)|(?1)|(?2)/
```

If your engine doesn't support that (**EDIT:** since you are using Java, no this feature is not supported), the best you can get in a single pattern is indeed

```
ab?|b
```

Alternatively, you can build the `ab|a|b` version manually by string concatenation/formatting like:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String pattern = a + b + "|" + a + "|" + b;
```

This avoids the duplication as well. Or you can use 3 separate patterns `ab`, `a` and `b` against the subject string (where the first one is again a concatenation of the latter two).

Comment: @leppie I think that's subjective, and if you do that you should use `(?:ab?)` - otherwise the brackets incur an unnecessary overhead by capturing the `ab` (maybe I should add that to the first solution)

Comment: +1 Regex: You learn something new everyday, even 40 years later ;p