# Refining a regex repeating group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract two sides of a string delimited by a hyphen

```
abc - def
```

At the moment I have

```
([^-]*)-([^-]*)
```

Match 1 would be `abc` and match 2 would be `def`.

Is there a more elegant way of writing this regular expression so that there are no repeating elements? i.e. `([^-]*)` is not repeated twice.

Comment: I think that regex is perfectly fine.

Comment: Agreed with @arshajii - this is not the case where you need to try do more simply way. If there were at least - well, 4 groups, then - yes, it'll make a sense.

Comment: Related: [Simplifying the regex “ab|a|b”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16217375/1225328)

Comment: In reality each side may not be as simple as ([^-]*). If it is 20 characters or something then repeating it all twice looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `[^-]+` and iterate over the results.

Illustration in Java:

```java
// yours
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("([^-]*)-([^-]*)").matcher("abc - def");
if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(1));
    System.out.println(m1.group(2));
}

// mine
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("[^-]+").matcher("abc - def");
while (m2.find()) {
    System.out.println(m2.group());
}
```

Outputs are identical.

Comment: I like this solution best. I assume find() is Java's version of std::regex_search or std::regex_iterator. Thanks sp00m.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy match:

```
(.*?)-(.*)
```

See a [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wV0aO8) showing it working.

I don't think it can be done more simply than this.

Comment: I never knew about this lazy operator, until now! Tnx

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear; I'm not trying to simplify the part inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You could just match `(.*)-(.*)`, the hyphen would still have to get matched so it would split the 2 expressions.
By the way, you can try checking online on sites like this - http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is more complex, you could split it up into smaller chunks and then reuse those.

For your example this could look like this (Java):

```
String side = "([^-]*)";
String regex = side + "-" + side;
```

However, while this is useful for repeated complex regexes (think e-mail validation and such), in your case the version with repetitions is perfectly okay.

You can refer to what was matched in an earlier group by using `([^-]*)-\1`, but this will only match if the two sides are *equal*, not if they match the same pattern, i.e., it would match `"abc-abc"`, but not `"abc-def"`.

Comment: There's no \1 equivalent for reusing a previous part of the expression, huh? I suppose const strings or a macro might be a more elegant way of representing what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
(?:[^-]*-?){2}
```

[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/xW7aP6)

Comment: Unfortunately i need to capture the text for processing. I couldn't make this approach work.

Comment: @user2675345 You mean you need to capture both sides in different capturing groups or you want the whole thing in one group ?

Comment: Capture each side separately.