# Java regex to match word with optional multiple comments between every 2 letters (how to back reference a regex subexpression)

Tags: java, regex, backreference

I need a java regex that matches a word, taking into account a possibility of a comment inside every 2 subsequent letters.
For example, `"W/*comment1*/OR/*comment2*/D"`.
I tried to use a named captured group and backreference:

```
(?<comment>\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)W\k<comment>*O\k<comment>*R\k<comment>*D
```

But that does not work, because backreference references a match of the named group, not the actual group subexpression.
So, I had to repeat a comment subexpression `(?<comment>\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)` in all places where it is expected:

```
W(\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)*O(\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)*R(\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)*D
```

This works, but is there any more elegant solution, without a need to repeat a "comment" subpattern many times?

Comment: an example of input output would have helped

Comment: What about stripping the comments first? I think it is the way to go. It makes the code way more simple and is likely as fast if not faster to run two simple regex than a complicated one. Plus it is easier to maintain and stuff...

Comment: @vks This is example: W/*comment1*/OR/*comment2*/D

Comment: Yeah and the output now?

Comment: @Johnride The OP just want to match, not to replace nor to split. So there is no expected output :)

Comment: @Johnride Yes, stripping comments looks like a solution, but I am interested to know if there is a solution via clean regex without prior preprocessing. Thanks for a nice idea!

Comment: Could [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217375/simplifying-the-regex-abab) help you?

Comment: @AlexanderLyakhovetskyy It would be simpler to dynamically construct the regex string by having `String commentRegExp = "(\s*/\*.*\*/\s*)"` and `String regExp = "W" + commentRegExp + "O" + commentRegExp + "R" + commentRegExp + "D"`

Comment: What about http://regex101.com/r/uU6cM7/3 or http://regex101.com/r/uU6cM7/2

Comment: @hwnd Yes,  [A-Z](?:\s*/\*[^*]*\*/\s*[A-Z])* works, thanks. But in real application I have much more complex regex where I need to reference a repeating subexpression in multiple places. It is not easy to embed a part of the expression (like, [A-Z] into comment subexpression.

Comment: @hwnd this doesn't match the string, only the "two letters"?

Comment: @Kent, I was just repeating the group of comments between. I am not sure what the OP extactly wants.

Comment: @sp00m Thanks, but it says: since you are using Java, no this feature is not supported

Comment: @hwnd Just finding a match for the entire string is good enough

Comment: @hwnd ah! `"W` the quote was not in the string... OP said every two letters, I thought `"W and D"` are in string with quotes included....

Comment: @hwnd I just mean that comment could be in between every two subsequent letters. This W/*comment1*/O/*comment2*/R/*comment3*/D should also match.

Comment: Well Java doesn't have support for recursive subpatterns, so your second attempt or http://regex101.com/r/uU6cM7/5 would likely be your bet using regex, which is ugly.

Comment: @hwnd Thanks for clearing this up for me

Comment: @AlexanderLyakhovetskyy: "I need to reference a repeating subexpression": There is no way to do this with Java regex. You can only have backreferences (the matched content), but you can't reuse a subpattern

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by capturing a letter (or several) at a time, while discarding optional following comments, like this:

```
        String toBeParsed="W/* this is comment 1 */OR/*this is comment 2*/D";
        String regexp = "(\\w+)(/\\*.*?\\*/)*"; // match letters + optional comment
        Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile(regexp);
        Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(toBeParsed);
        String word="";
        while(matcher.find()){
            String letter=matcher.group(1);
            String comment=matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("found letter(s) "+letter);
            word+=letter;
            if (comment!=null) System.out.println("discarding comment "+matcher.group(2));
        }
        System.out.println(word);
```

the output is

```
found letter(s) W
discarding comment /* this is comment 1 */
found letter(s) OR
discarding comment /*this is comment 2*/
found letter(s) D
WORD
```

Comment: Or maybe even in phrases of words: `"(\w+)(/\\*[a-zA-Z0-9\s!:?_*]*?\\*/)*"`. OP said "word" so I am assuming they mean only alpha characters, but I doubt that is using non alpha characters. Also, OP didn't say that the comment didn't have spaces in it, so I changed the qualifier for the comment.

Comment: Yes, in phrases of words is a better idea. I will amend my solution accordingly

Answer (score 0):

"how to back reference a regex subexpression"

you mean this? :

```
"(.*)\\1"
```

This matches any duplicated word. \1 refers to the first group, which is the first bracketed part.